# creating dropdownlists programmatically inside web forms user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, telerik-ajax

I've been trying out telerik's ajax controls and so far they haven't given me huge problems. I'm using their ajax radgrid with editing capabilities and one of their suggestions is to use a web forms user control (.ascx) filled programmatically with controls to edit a particular grid record.

I can open the web form just fine and also fill it in code-behind with the following controls:

- textboxes
- labels
- dropdownlists

For the grid I've been testing the edit functionality, to edit a record i need 3 dropdownlists in order to properly edit it, now this is where my problems start.

I have a function that adds records if they match certain metadata criteria, if I put a breakpoint in between adding the controls and do the following steps:

- add the first "line" of controls (label and textbox)
- add the second "line" of controls (label and dropdownlist)

  **If i stop here and step into to end the function the following happens, both labels have the right text as well as the textbox but the dropdownlist not so much, even though I have set the selected index do value "2" and in quickwatch it stays at 2, once the web form is displayed the default value value resets to "0"**
- add the third "line" of controls (label and dropdownlist)

  **If i stop here and step into the end of the function, even though in quickwatch everything is fine, once the web form is displayed/loaded, both dropdownlists will have the same values inside them and they will both have their selectedindex = 0**

edit:i'll describe the behaviour i'm expecting:

1. the first **dropdown(1)** to be filled with for example "None,A,B,C,D,E,F,G" and have "A" as the selecteditem
2. the second **dropdown(2)** to be filled with for example "None,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6" and have "F3" as the selecteditem

this is behaviour i'm getting:

once the web form is loaded, **dropdown(1) and dropdown(2)** are filled with "None,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6" and their selected value is "None" even though it was set to something else

am i missing some special ascx related event?

here's some of my code:

**details.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Details.ascx.vb" Inherits="Project.Details" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

     <div id="template_edit" style="background-color:red" runat="server">
        <%-- div onto which all my controls are addded --%>


    </div>

    <div id="editfooter">
            <asp:Button ID="Button_aceitar" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Visible="true"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="PerformInsert" Visible="true"></asp:Button>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button_cancelar" Text="Cancelar" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>

            <asp:Label ID="LabelLOG" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

**some of the code behind on details.ascx.vb**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If IsPostBack Then
Try
                    sOper = Session("OPERACAO_Edit")
                    gPeriodo = Session("PERIODO_Edit")
                    gClasse = Session("CLASSE_Edit")
                    gSistema = Session("SISTEMA_Edit")
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

gEG = Session("EntidGest")
                Select Case gClasse & gSistema
                    Case 11
                        gMNID = 1
                    Case 12
                        gMNID = 2
                    Case 21
                        gMNID = 3
                    Case 22
                        gMNID = 4
                    Case 31
                        gMNID = 5
                    Case 32
                        gMNID = 6
                End Select

                Add_Controls(sOper)

Else
                gPeriodo = Request.QueryString("periodo")
                gClasse = Request.QueryString("classe")
                gSistema = Request.QueryString("sistema")
                gEG = Session("EntidGest")
                Select Case gClasse & gSistema
                    Case 11
                        gMNID = 1
                    Case 12
                        gMNID = 2
                    Case 21
                        gMNID = 3
                    Case 22
                        gMNID = 4
                    Case 31
                        gMNID = 5
                    Case 32
                        gMNID = 6
                End Select
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub


Private Sub Detail_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Try

            gVALIDATETEXT = "a-záâàãéêèíîìóôòõúûùçA-ZÁÂÀÃÉÊÈÍÎÌÓÔÒÕÚÛÙÇ .,;:/+\?!0-9<>_=&-"
            gVALIDATETEXT = gVALIDATETEXT.Replace("a-z", "")
            gVALIDATETEXT = gVALIDATETEXT.Replace("A-Z", "")
            gVALIDATETEXT = gVALIDATETEXT.Replace("0-9", "")

        Catch ex As Exception
            gText = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & " Erro: " & Me.Page.ToString & " " & ex.Message
            Add2LogFile(glogpath, gText)
        End Try
    End Sub




    Private Sub Add_Controls(ByVal bOper As String)


'this bit of code is inside a loop that goes through some metadata, creates and adds controls to a div 
        Dim oCmb As New DropDownList
        Dim oTextBox As New TextBox
        Dim gSqlCMB As New SqlDataSource
        Dim sValue as String

        oCmb = New DropDownList
        oCmb.ID = 'something dynamic

        gSQL = "select c,t from table" 'the query is different for each dropdownlist
        gSqlCMB.SelectCommand = gSQL
        oCmb.DataSource = gSqlCMB
        oCmb.DataValueField = "C"
        oCmb.DataTextField = "T"
        oCmb.SelectedValue = sValue '"1", "2", "3"....
        oCmb.DataBind()
        template_edit.controls.Add(oCmb)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the problem is.

Comment: i've bolded the problems, i hope that helps

Comment: It would help if you told us what behavior you're actually expecting.

Comment: i'm sorry for that, my english is very rusty. i hope you can understand the post now